# Site pages not scrollable after adding angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a site that was downloaded first as a template. in order to convert into an angular app, i removed all the `<head>`, `<html>` and `<body>` tags of all other pages except the index page which contains the `<ng-view>`. now the routing is working just fine to redirect to all the pages but the problem is that the pages are not scrolling anymore. the index.html page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="IndexController">
<head>
<title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view [onload="string"]
     [autoscroll="string"]></div>


</body>
</html>
```

and the other pages look something like this

```
<div>
<!-- page content goes here-->
</div>
```

app config is like

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','LocalStorageModule','ngStorage']);

app.config(
    function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {templateUrl : "home.html", controller: 'HomeController' })

//other routes
        
});
```

when i run this site, all the pages that have long content are cut short and cannot scroll to view the rest of the content. please help. I have been working with angularjs for some time now but i have never come across anything like this before.

Comment: not 100%, though think `<div ng-view [onload="string" [autoscroll="string"]></div>` should actually be `<div ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>`; unless you're using onload don't include it.

Comment: Thanx for response but i added this after finding out that my pages are not scrollable. its the only solution i came across after hours of searching before deciding to post a question here